# How to copy file from buildSrc into main build

Tags: gradle

I have a custom task in `buildSrc` that, among other things, I want to copy a file *from* `buildSrc` into the main build. However, when actually running the custom task, the `buildSrc` project appears to be pretty much invisible, e.g. I can't reference it as a project. How does one refer to and copy a file from the `buildSrc` project to the main project?

Comment: Please share your `build.gradle` file and the possible scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the main projects can not see `buildSrc`. `buildSrc` is run as a separate project.

The outputs of `buildSrc` project are put onto the classpath of the main Gradle projects.

One solution then is to generate a Jar artifact with all of your resources, and then use the classpath resource loader in the main projects to access the files you need.

A second option might be to just manually hard code the `buildSrc` path into your main projects. Of course you can not access it as `project(:buildSrc')` because it is not valid. The better option is to use `file("${rootProject}/buildSrc/")` (*Not tested*).

Comment: Thanks cmcginty -- I actually did end up going with your second suggestion for now. I might circle back later and try the JAR approach, but...doesn't yet seem like it'd provide enough value.